# Auto run command in linux

Tags: rsync

I am trying to automate backup with rsync to an external hard disk. What I want to do is to execute this command automatically when external hard disk is plugged. I do not want to run it when other hard disk or flash drive is plugged in. Can some please point me in the right direction. I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Here is the command which I am planning to use.

```
rsync -arLth --progress --exclude-from '/home/user1/.backupExclude' /home/user1 media/user1/T500Backup/
```

and here is my .backupExclude file

```
user1@SCAR:~$ tail ~/.backupExclude 
Dropbox
Movies
user1@SCAR:~$
```

Comment: You can do this with udev, i don't remember exactly how.

Comment: Definitely check out udev.

Comment: Actually, using udisks is a better abstraction for this, listen for events on system dbus.

Comment: Run `udisksctl monitor` to see what events you get and what info there is, such as drive number.

Comment: @Keith: This is awesome. I can use ID or serial#. But how, that is the big question. Others mentioned udev. I am still trying to figure out how I can use it.

Comment: You want to write a script? Or looking for an existing tool?

Comment: Which ever is more robust and reliable and preferably simple.